# Does std::scientific always result in normalized scientific notation for floating-point numbers?

Tags: c++, floating-point, scientific-notation

Scientific notation defines how numbers should be displayed using a sign, a number and an exponent but it does not state that the visualization is normalized.

An example: **-2.34e-2** (normalized scientific notation) is the same as **-0.234e-1** (scientific notation)

Can I rely on the following code always producing the normalized outcome?
**Edit:** except NAN and INF as pointed out in the answers.

```
template<typename T>
static std::string toScientificNotation(T number, unsigned significantDigits)
{
    if (significantDigits > 0) {
        significantDigits--;
    }
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.precision(significantDigits);
    ss << std::scientific << number;
    return ss.str();
}
```

If yes, please list a section in the C++ documentation/standard stating that it is not platform/implementation-defined. Since the value of 0 is also represented differently I'm afraid that certain very small numbers (denormalized?!) could be visualized differently. On my platform with my compiler it currently works for std::numeric_limits::min(), denorm_min().

Note: I use this to find the order of magnitude of a number without messing with all the quirky details of floating point number analysis. I wanted the standard library do it for me :-)

Comment: Why not a simple `std::log10` if you want the order of magnitude?

Comment: Because this yields the wrong results. An example: 999.0f has a magnitude of 2. When used for metric prefix notation this is unfortunately wrong because you need to take the significant digits into account. The magnitude is 2 for 3 significant digits but is 3 for 2 significant digits because the value is rounded to 1000. In short: 999.0f with 2 sig digits -> "1.0k", 999.0f with 3 sig digits -> "999"

Comment: *"the wrong result"* - Well, you should add to your question what you want exactly. You can always play around with logarithm / rounding and multiplying to get the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, except for zero, infinity and NaN.

The C++ standard refers to the C standard for formatting, which requires normalized scientific notation.

- [[floatfield.manip]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/floatfield.manip#lib:scientific)

  > ```
  > ios_base& scientific(ios_base& str);
  > ```
  >
  > Effects: Calls `str.setf(ios_­base​::​scientific, ios_­base​::​floatfield)`.
  >
  > Returns: `str`.
- [[ostream.inserters.arithmetic]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.inserters.arithmetic#itemdecl:1) (partial)

  > ```
  > operator<<(float val);
  > operator<<(double val);
  > operator<<(long double val);
  > ```
  >
  > Effects: **The classes `num_­get<>` and `num_­put<>` handle locale-dependent numeric formatting and parsing.** These inserter functions use the imbued `locale` value to perform numeric formatting. When `val` is of type ..., `double`, `long double`, ..., the formatting conversion occurs as if it performed the following code fragment:
  >
  > ```
  > bool failed = use_facet<
  >   num_put<charT, ostreambuf_iterator<charT, traits>>
  >     >(getloc()).put(*this, *this, fill(), val).failed();
  > ```
  >
  > When `val` is of type `float` the formatting conversion occurs as if it performed the following code fragment:
  >
  > ```
  > bool failed = use_facet<
  >   num_put<charT, ostreambuf_iterator<charT, traits>>
  >     >(getloc()).put(*this, *this, fill(),
  >       static_cast<double>(val)).failed();
  > ```
- [[facet.num.put.virtuals]/1:5.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/facet.num.put.virtuals#5.1) (partial)

  > - Stage 1:
  >
  >   The first action of stage 1 is to determine a conversion specifier. The tables that describe this determination use the following local variables
  >
  >   ```
  >   fmtflags flags = str.flags();
  >   fmtflags floatfield = (flags & (ios_base::floatfield));
  >   ```
  >
  >   For conversion from a floating-point type, the function determines the floating-point conversion specifier as indicated in Table 70.
  >
  >   Table 70 — Floating-point conversions
  >
  >   ```
  >   | State                                            | stdio equivalent |
  >   | ------------------------------------------------ | ---------------- |
  >   | floatfield == ios_­base​::​scientific && !uppercase | %e               |
  >   | floatfield == ios_­base​::​scientific               | %E               |
  >   ```
  >
  >   The representations at the end of stage 1 consists of the `char`'s **that would be printed by a call of `printf(s, val)`** where `s` is the conversion specifier determined above.
- C11 n1570 [7.21.6.1]:8.4

  > - **e**,**E**
  >
  >   A `double` argument representing a floating-point number is converted in the
  >     style *[−]d.ddd***e***±dd*, **where there is one digit (which is nonzero if the
  >     argument is nonzero) before the decimal-point character** and the number of
  >     digits after it is equal to the precision; if the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is zero and the **#** flag is not specified, no decimal-point
  >     character appears. The value is rounded to the appropriate number of digits. The **E** conversion specifier produces a number with **E** instead of **e**
  >     introducing the exponent. The exponent always contains at least two digits,
  >     and only as many more digits as necessary to represent the exponent. **If the
  >     value is zero, the exponent is zero.**
  >
  >   A `double` argument representing an infinity or NaN is converted in the style of an **f** or **F** conversion specifier.

Comment: Wow, thanks! This answer is amazingly detailed and exactly what I was looking for! :-)

Comment: That's an excellent answer. I completely missed that table 70, well done!

Answer (score 4):

> Can I rely on the following code always producing the normalized outcome?

There are no guarantee of it, no. Better said: the Standard does not impose a guarantee as strong as you wish here was.

`std::scientific` is only quoted on the following relevant parts:

1. [`[floatfield.manip]:2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/floatfield.manip#itemdecl:2)

   > ```
   > ios_base& scientific(ios_base& str);
   > ```
   >
   > *Effects*: Calls `str.setf(ios_­base​::​scientific, ios_­base​::​floatfield)`.
   >   *Returns*: `str`.
2. [Table 101 — fmtflags effects](http://eel.is/c++draft/ios::fmtflags#tab:iostreams.fmtflags.effects)

   > ```
   > | Element    | Effect(s) if set                                       |
   > | ...        | ...                                                    |
   > | scientific | generates floating-point output in scientific notation |
   > | ...        | ...                                                    |
   > ```

Comment: ͏+͏1͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏. I do find it amazing that ISO have not defined what scientific notation is.

Comment: @Bathsheba Maybe you do have a proper copy of an ISO C++ document, referencing another ISO defining "scientific notation"?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have any idea of a high-level approach to visualize floating point numbers in the metric prefix notation (m, µ, G, etc.)? My code is very well unit tested and it would also help a lot to have a solid way to determine the order of magnitude of a number. Tons of code pieces here on SO and elsewhere are simply wrong. They only cover the most obvious scenarios. I need a bullet proof solution and cannot believe that there is nothing in the standard or in boost :-(

Comment: @FrozenTarzan Not that I'm aware of. You'd need a specific tool if it exists, or build your own. If you make your mind and go with the later and find yourself stuck so you ask a question on SO, ping me here ;)

Comment: @YSC I would be very interested in your comment on the accepted answer so I could sleep even better keeping my code like that ;-)